# How to implement copy(sender: AnyObject?) in NSTableView?

Tags: swift, nstableview

I'm develop a macOS app with an NSTableView and I want to give the ability to copy the content of a cell with Cmd+C shortcut when the user select a row.
I have implemented the method

```
copy(sender: AnyObject?)
```

in my view controller but I am unable to copy the content.

What is the right way to implement this feature?
Thanks
Michele

Comment: Basically it's the right way. In the body of the method you have to gather the information you need from the cell view and put it on the [pasteboard](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard). And consider that your syntax of `copy` is Swift 2

Comment: I know how to get the informations to put in the pasteboard but the problem is that when I select a row in the table view the Copy action in the menu remains inactive.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same thing.  It started working for me when I changed:

```
copy(sender: AnyObject?)
```

to

```
 @objc func copy(_ sender: AnyObject?)
```

Both the `@objc` and the `_` seem to matter.